# titleformat and rotatebox: missing text with LaTeX => PS => PDF output profile

Tags: microtype, dvi-mode

I modified my `\part` and `\chapter` style with `\titleformat` and it works just fine when i use the LaTeX=>PDF output profile. In the end I want to use the LaTeX => PS => PDF output profile but as soon as I use it the rotated text (Part or Chapter) is gone. I'm not sure if it is `\titleformat` or `\rotatebox` that is responsible...

How can I make the text appear with LaTeX=>PS=>PDF?

Here's the minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside, english]{report}


\usepackage{titlesec}               
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}                   


\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,255} 



\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {\filleft\hspace*{-60pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \normalfont\color{myblue}\Huge%
        \textls[180]{\textsc{\partname}}%
    }\hspace{10pt}%
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{%
      \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thepart}% 
    }}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE \pagestyle{empty}}                                                                           





\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\end{document}
```

I can also upload pics of it if it helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Package `microtype` tells you what is going on when you run LaTeX on your file:

```
Package microtype Warning: You are using tracking/letterspacing in DVI mode.
(microtype)                This will probably not work, unless the post-
(microtype)                processing program (dvips, dvipdfm(x), ...) is
(microtype)                able to create the virtual fonts on the fly.
```

The command `\textls` does not work in dvi mode.  You could try the `\caps` command from`soul.sty` for your use case:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside, english,dvips]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\usepackage{soul}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\color{myblue}}
  {\filleft\hspace*{-60pt}%
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
      \normalfont\color{myblue}\Huge%
      \caps\partname %% <==========
    }\hspace{10pt}%
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \colorbox{myblue}{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2.5cm}{%
      \centering\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont\thepart}%
    }}%
  }
  {10pt}
  {\titlerule[2.5pt]\vskip3pt\titlerule\vskip4pt\LARGE \pagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \verb|\normalfont First Part| & \normalfont First Part \\
  \verb|\scshape First Part|    & \scshape First Part \\
  \verb|\caps{First Part}|      & \caps{First Part}
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

`\caps` is a letterspacing command.  The result of the code above is:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks
it also works by killing the \textls command \textsc{\partname} The increased letter spacing would be nice but i can live with it now.